# Parent node workspace of Matrix jobs in Jenkins

Tags: matrix, jenkins

When using the repo plugin in Jenkins for multi configuration jobs.

The source code is checked out once in the matrix parent workspace and then again in all the nodes where the multi configuration job spawns.

Is there a way to avoid the source code checkout on the parent node, which seems to be a duplication and unnecessary wastage of time when the same code is again going to be checked out in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid it. That's the way the multi-configuration job works. Your options are:

- Do not use multi-configuration job. You can replace it with multiple jobs or with a single job that takes a parameter or parameters and trigger all those jobs.
- Keep using multi-configuration job but minimize the downsides of the parent checkout by having enough disk space for it and/or making sure the checkout is as fast as possible. There are ways to speed up a checkout but how exactly to do it depends on which version control system you use.

Comment: Great, any idea how the checkouts can be speed-ed in git.

Comment: You could use a reference repo or shallow clone. Check the advanced options offered by jenkins git plugin. Also, you can let the workspace remain on disk which makes next build faster.

Comment: Guess you are talking about having a local mirror and use it as a reference to sync the code. Yep using that as of now. Thanks